# Creating Adaptive Cards with copy functionality

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

Before I get started, I first want to say I am NOT a developer, but I am forced into a limited role in our Organization. We are a Law Enforcement agency that is using Microsoft 365 Gov. I have created a Power Automate task that pulls specific emails from Outlook and Post them to a Teams Channel. In side that Bot message is a License Plate number. I have found a ton of articles on developing Adaptive Cards.

My scenerio:
I need an a Power Automate task that pulls new emails from an outlook account, post the Adaptive Card to MS Teams Channel, and has a copy button on the card that, somehow, copies the License Plate posted on the card.

I am pretty sure that some type of parsing is needed. I have a degree and lots of training in IT, but limited education on development. Out department has no budget for expensive development work, so I am trying to figure this out on my own.

Thanks for all that help.

I tried using Power Automate ad using predesigned options, but adaptive cards is looking for JSON code, not sure where to get code for the porject we are attempting.

Comment: What do you mean by "copies" the license plate? Like into the clipboard?

Comment: In terms of parsing, the best way to parse 'patterns' in text is to use Regular Expressions (RegEx). It's an extremely mature and well supported pattern matching framework available in pretty much every major programming language and platform, but it's NOT natively in Power Automate. You need to use a 3rd party paid option, or a Premium connector, or some kind of mixed solution like this: https://andersjensen.org/how-to-use-regex-in-power-automate/ . You can also Google "Rexex Power Automate" for others.

Comment: This will all only work with standard license plate patterns though, not necessarily with vanity plates...

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the entire email looks like? Also, “copies”?!? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hilton. Yes. Copy into clipboard

Comment: Email Example is like this that comes in from an email alert 

FL - RNS072 Invalid License
Event Time: 23:21:07 07/24/2023
Source: FL Sanctioned Drivers
Vehicle Make: CHEV
Vehicle Color: BGE
Camera: #01 Hwy 79 @ 277 NB

Comment: I then created a Power Automate for Teams that imports that email into a channel so the crews can see the alert and make a traffic stop. My hope is that somewhere inside the Teams Card I can have a "Copy License Plate" button that only copies the 
RNS072

Comment: Sorry I cannot post pictures. It would make this visually a lot easier to explain. If someone is considering assisting further I can email the items you are requesting to see.